# Is there a way to only pass a certain variable and it's value with the include function?

Tags: php

I want to include a page that contains a variable with a value that I need to insert in a database, but when I include the page, functions out of the scope of the second page try to run, which leads to an undefined error.

Basically I want this:

```
mainpage.php

    <?php
    $variable = 'value';
    function();
    ?>
```

secondpage.php

```
    <?php
    include 'mainpage.php';

    echo $variable;
    ?>
```

But I cant do this without also calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

PHP executes statements line-by-line, so you cannot control what it does unless your `mainpage.php` has some conditional statements that you can influence from within `secondpage.php`.

Comment: Exactly. You could f.ex. put an `if (isset($included) && $included === true)` around the function, and then set the $included variable to true in secondpage.php :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside function type,

```
global $variable;
```

So your page will look like this:

```
$variable = 'value';
function();
echo $variable;
```

So if you want to function() to access $variable, you need to put global $variable inside function, echo $variable should echo "value".